# Why am I getting the same MD5 checksum for seemingly different inputs using Perl's Digest::MD5?

Tags: perl, md5, md5sum

On my Linux platform with 64bits recompiled `perl` and SSHing Mac terminal (I guess UTF-8). I am giving all this information just in case it might be relevant.

```
# perl -e 'use Digest::MD5 qw/md5_hex/; print(md5_hex("alex@vi\n") ."\n");'
756e98065cb8cbf603a3dbef2afe9261

# perl -e 'use Digest::MD5 qw/md5_hex/; print(md5_hex("alex@visi\n") ."\n");'
756e98065cb8cbf603a3dbef2afe9261

# perl -e 'use Digest::MD5 qw/md5_hex/; print(md5_hex("alex@vision\n") ."\n");'
756e98065cb8cbf603a3dbef2afe9261

# perl -e 'use Digest::MD5 qw/md5_hex/; print(md5_hex("alex@visionten\n") ."\n");'
756e98065cb8cbf603a3dbef2afe9261

# perl -e 'use Digest::MD5 qw/md5_hex/; print(md5_hex("alex@visionten.\n") ."\n");'
d32e04de6906b3f284c6834b4d1d77c1

# perl -e 'use Digest::MD5 qw/md5_hex/; print(md5_hex("alex@\n") ."\n");'
264eca1047ccc6272ac2e338c695379e
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the inputs to md5_hex just prior to calling the function?

Comment: Always enable warnings; even (or perhaps especially?) on one-liners.

Comment: Right, either `-Mstrict` or `-w` on the command line would have revealed the problem.

Comment: Here is a shorter style for writing one-liners:
`perl -MDigest::MD5=md5_hex -wE "say md5_hex(qq/alex\@vi\n/);"`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are using @ inside a double-quoted string. All of the @vision and @visionten things are evaluating to the same thing.

Comment: Correct. Perl is interpolating the embedded @vision and @visionten as arrays which are empty, resulting in nothing being output. Printing the md5_hex() parameter strings will show most of the strings end up evaluating to "alex\n"

Comment: @hobbs: For one-liners that is a bit more difficult.

Comment: No more difficult than in any other context, @Kinopiko.

Comment: @Kinopiko `-mstrict` is even shorter than `use strict` :)

Comment: @alex: everybody who uses Perl has made the same mistake at least once.